# Apache showing default page to alternative domain

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, vhosts

I have two different domains that are supposed to point exactly to the same `index.php` file:

1. `diegodeoxossi.com.br`
2. `lumelivros.com.br`

All DNS settings for both are the same. Apache default vhost is disabled and both domains has the same vhost configs, as below:

#1 `diegodeoxossi.com.br`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName diegodeoxossi.com.br
ServerAlias *.diegodeoxossi.com.br
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
AllowEncodedSlashes On

<Directory /var/www/html>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
SSLProxyEngine On

</VirtualHost>
```

#2 `lumelivros.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName lumelivros.com
ServerAlias *.lumelivros.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
AllowEncodedSlashes On

<Directory /var/www/html>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
SSLProxyEngine On

</VirtualHost>
```

They all point to the same root directory, and both pass by `.htaccess` - and here is the problem: my last line in `.htaccess` is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*         site/index.php?APPLR_friendlyURL=1 [L,QSA]
```

The thing is: domain #1 works great; domain #2 pass by this rule and keeps showing Apache's default page. Does any one have a clue on how to fix it?

Comment: If you want to show the same website why not just use the `ServerAlias` for the second domain name?

Comment: Actually, after I can get both domains properly showing the same basic site, application will control different contents... "show exactly the same website" in my question actually means "point to the same index.php file" (I´ll edit it)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ServerName lumelivros.com
> ```

You are missing the `.br` TLD that is present in the example, so the request will never match the stated VirtualHost. The request is likely being caught by the "default" vHost container and the expected `.htaccess` file is not even being processed.

> Apache default vhost is disabled

You can't "disable" the default vhost. Whatever vHost is defined *first* is considered the *default*. So, there is always a *default*, even if you have not explicitly defined one.

However, as already mentioned in comments, if you want both domains to serve the same site (and the response is determined by the application) then you should only have a single vHost container that serves both domains.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName diegodeoxossi.com.br
    ServerAlias *.diegodeoxossi.com.br
    ServerAlias lumelivros.com.br
    ServerAlias *.lumelivros.com.br
    :
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> SSLProxyEngine On
> ```

These two directives are out of place here. (?)